# Retrieving Family information from Facebook using FQL?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

Hi I am trying to pull information from Facebook using FQL. I was able to gather info on my friends and the profile users likes however I cant seem to get a list of family information, the code I currently have is below. I was wondering if anyone could help and let me know what I am doing wrong, any help would be great appreciated, thanks

```
<h1>My Family</h1>
      <?php
              $user    = $facebook->getUser();
              $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

              $fql_query  =   array(
                  'method'    => 'fql.query',
                  'query'     => "SELECT profile_id, name, relationship FROM family WHERE profile_id={$user}");
              $family = $facebook->api($fql_query);
              $fam = count($family);
              echo $fam;

              for ($i=0;$i<$fam;$i++){
                echo "<p>".$family[$i]['name']." ".$family[$i]['relationship']." from ".$family[$i]['sex']." </p>";
              }
         ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need friends_relationships extended permission to get access to the user's family.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

also "sex" you have there seems unrelated

Comment: Hi, yes I have this permission in already forgot to mention that, but it still doesn't work, is there any other resources online to teach you FQL step by step other than the faceook for developers? (yeah the 'sex' shouldnt be there)

Comment: your FQL seems OK and works for me so I guess it is either permissions issue or user privacy issue: user can make their family information private or even opt-out from facebook API platform. You can try another user or your own user to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need `user_relationships` permission to view the user's family info.